# How to view HTML mails in Claws?

Tags: mail, gmail, html, claws

I've just installed claws mail. Setting it up was not easy, but thanks to [this](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/817542-gmail-friendly-email-clients-available-on-linux/) sit I've managed to retrieve my mails. Only, html mails are just displayed as plain text so i've installed fancy plugin and under settings -> preferences -> display messages -> i've deselected 'display html messages as text' and selected ' If possible display html messages with plugin'. 
Under the settings for fancy plugin 'display embedded messages' is also selected but still the same: hml messages are just ugly text. 
What did i do wrong?

Answer (score 3):

It works. Once you enabled the above mentioned setting, open the HTML mail by double clicking it. Then you can see small buttons on the right side of the mail window when you move the mouse pointer over that, it shows "text/html". Click it and then you can view HTML enabled mails.

Comment: Indeed, now I see it also. But you have to click on it for every mail. Is there an option to view HTML by default?

Answer (score 2):

I had some success with Configuration>Preferences>Message View>Text Options>Render HTML-only messages with plugin if possible. I had to un-check enable loading of remote content in the fancy plugin, click apply, then travel back to text options, check that, click apply, then travel back to fancy, check Enable, click apply, and it worked. Best of luck
Rock hard
Ride free

Comment: No luck with this. Guess I'll take another email client (read: easier). Thx for your help

Answer (score 0):

Just enable all checkboxes in the HTML messages groupbox to enable automatic HTML rendering when you enter a message in a message list.